# $q - Control order of function execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I'm trying to structure a function with a promise so something only runs once the previous function has completed.

I have an array of invoices.  Each invoice does not store customer information except for a customer reference number. Using the customer reference number, I would like to query my API for the customer name using the reference number.

```
    $scope.invoices.forEach(function(invoice) {

        var defer = $q.defer();

        defer.promise.then(function(invoice) {

            var customer_id = invoice[$rootScope.data]["Id"][0].match(/\d+/)[0];

            $http.post('/customers', customer_id).success(function(response) {
                console.log("Response is: " + response);
                return response;
            });

        }).then(function(result) {
            invoice.customer_name = result;
            console.log("The final result is: " + result);
            return invoice.customer_name;
        });

        defer.resolve(invoice);
    });
```

Note: For now, my API only returns the reference number given.

In my console, I see the following output:

```
(10) The final result is: undefined
Response is: 235
Response is: 239
Response is: 234
Response is: 238
Response is: 237
Response is: 236
Response is: 233
Response is: 232
Response is: 231
Response is: 230
```

How ensure the second `then` is only run after the first?

Comment: use `$q.all(arrayOfPostPromises)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical approach in such cases is to use `$q.all` with array of promises. It's convenient to compose such array using `Array.prototype.map` method:

```
var promises = $scope.invoices.map(function(invoice) {

    var customer_id = invoice[$rootScope.data]["Id"][0].match(/\d+/)[0];

    return $http.post('/customers', customer_id).then(function(result) {
        invoice.customer_name = result.data;
        console.log("The final result is: " + result);
        return invoice.customer_name;
    });
});

$q.all(promises).then(function(responses) {
    // console.log(responses);
});
```

When `$q.all` promise resolve you should get an array of customer names in correct order.